# Vimeo search API for related videos

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

Can I somehow make a search request for related videos (related to video from given id)?

Something similar to `vimeo.categories.getRelatedVideos`, but for `vimeo.videos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods you described are part of the old API. It is deprecated and will not continue to be supported. The new api (https://developer.vimeo.com/api) exposes some related videos through https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#GET/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D/videos.

Comment: Oh, amazing, thank you, sometimes this documentation is a bit confusing to navigate around if you have not so much patience.

Comment: Hello again, i got my hands on testing vimeo relateds, but for some reason i always recieve 'you have provided an invalid filter parameter' error.
I'm using vimeo API for Node.js and trying to get relateds like this: 
`Vlib.request({
            path: '/videos/' + id + '/videos'
        }, function (error, body, status_code, headers) {//cb})`
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: specifing `query: {filter: 'related'}` made it, but in documentation it seems that no fields required to make this request. So, is it possible mistake in docs or node.js api?

Comment: Looks to be a bug in our documentation generator. I'm fixing that now!

Comment: Dashron, i got a quick question and it seems that it's way too small to create new one, i'm trying to find any info in current  vimeo api docs about how to filter videos from video search endpoint by content rating, and i can not see anything relevant on API or endpoints page, would you mind throwing a link at me?